# How can i load a specific CSS file for a specific View?

Tags: views, theming

What's the best way (best practice) to load a specific stylesheet for specific View. i managed to do it like this, in the template.php file but i'm thinking this is pretty awkward and there is a better way.

```
if($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][0] == 'page__dvd_products') {

drupal_add_css(path_to_theme(). '/css/dvd-product-display-view.css', array('group'=>CSS_THEME));
} else {

drupal_add_css(path_to_theme(). '/css/dvd-product-display.css', array('group'=>CSS_THEME));
}
```

what is a better way to do this? i'm still kind of new at this. any feedback would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [Code per Views Display](https://drupal.org/project/cpv) module.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid installing additional modules when you don't have to. If you have a custom module, you can use hook_views_pre_build(&$view) as in below:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_build(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'NAME_OF_VIEW_HERE') { // put the name of the view here
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme(). '/css/dvd-product-display-view.css', array('group'=> CSS_THEME));
  }
}
```

See https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/7 for more info on hook_views_prebuild(&$view).

Also, if you use Views PHP (https://drupal.org/project/views_php), you can add a PHP area to the header and add the drupal_add_css() lines there.

Comment: thanks but i don't know what you mean when referring to additional modules. i was referring to a specific page view.